# Askers should see their answers' vote counts

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, votes

Question authors should be able to see the count of upvotes and downvotes on answers to their questions in order to better evaluate the answers: an answer with 100 upvotes and 100 downvotes is controversial, while an answer with 0 and 0 is not. (Vote counts are visible to those with 1000 reputation points, but anyone can ask a question.)

Comment: Vote count is theoretically public through the posters rep page.

Comment: @DoubleAA, yes, but it requires collating.

Comment: For sure, I'm just pointing out that the issue is one of making something convenient not releasing secret info.

Comment: Shouldn't votes by users who have greater reputation amount be worth more, possibly enough to balance out such a 100+100- scenario?

Comment: @AdamMosheh they aren't. If you think they should be, you can [meta-tag:feature-request] it.

Comment: @msh210 - http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1257/1059